# Power Bi Report Builder - Calculating change from last year

Tags: reporting-services, pagination, powerbi, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder

So I have 2 datasets. One is stats for year 2022, one is stats for 2021. I want to compare the numbers (totals) for each year in each category. I did this by creating a tablix using the wizard for each dataset. The last column is a measure imported from the data set and it calculates the percentage change from the same total in the previous year. As you see everything matches except the totals highlighted in red. For example, Full-Time Domestic is 18 in 2022 which is down 66.67% from 2021's number which is 54. This is correct, however the total: 284 in 2022 is not down 74.31% from 2021; It is summing the changes. I tried removing the sum() function but it just returns the first number (-66.67%) instead of the actual change. I'm still fairly new to power bi and report builder so I'm not sure how to fix it. I've blurred some info for privacy reasons.
[Screen Shot of Tablix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiWgC.jpg)

Comment: You'll need to show your report design, dataset and expressions used to do the calculations. Without this, it will be difficult for anyone to help you